# Change color to unselected row in JTable

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, cellrenderer

I need to highlight the color of a selected row in a JTable. I'm using my own CellRenderer for this, and it works, but when i select another row, the previous one still stays highlighted. The idea is to keep in blue color just the selected one, and keep in it's original color the other ones. In adittion i'm making the pair columns: gray and the non pair: white, so this is the code at the CellRenderer

```
private class Renderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
                                         boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
                                         int row, int column)
    {
        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected,
                                                          hasFocus, row, column);

        int columnIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
        int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();

        if (columnIndex != -1 && rowIndex != -1){
            this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            if (row % 2 == 0) this.setBackground(Color.decode("0xF9F9F9"));
            else this.setBackground(Color.decode("0xF1F1F1"));
        }
        return this;
    }
}
```

EDIT: F1F1F1 is a color nearly to white and F9F9F9F9 is kinda a light gray

Answer (score 5):

You should add something like the code below before you return from the method:

```
if (!isSelected) {
  setBackground(...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind using 3th party libs: the `JXTable` of the SwingX project has built-in support for alternating row colors using `HighLighter`s.

I found [an article](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/m91834162.html) which shows some screenshots of the result of applying a `HighLighter` to the `JXTable`. Problem is that the article is not up-to-date. The functionality is still there but the code has changed. While the article still mentions the `AlternateRowHighligher` as shown here

```
HighlighterPipeline highlighters = new HighlighterPipeline();
highlighters.addHighlighter(new AlternateRowHighlighter());
table.setHighlighters(highlighters);
```

the current approach would be more like

```
JXTable table;
Highlighter alternateStriping = 
  HighlighterFactory.createAlternateStriping( Color.decode( "0xF9F9F9" ), 
                                              Color.decode( "0xF1F1F1" ) );
table.setHighlighters( alternateStriping );
```

Comment: If i don't get an alternative ill get in this

Comment: @user1715408 The answer of Dan should allow you to fix your issue. I just wanted to show an alternative approach, and it was a bit long to include in a comment

Comment: I don't find a way to know when a row is selected... getSelectedRow() just return the index of the selected row...

Comment: @user1715408 the selected state of the row is passed as a parameter in the `getTableCellRenderer` method